# Different database for production and development in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sqlite, heroku, configuration

I know that Ruby on Rails has this feature, and in the railstutorial it specifically encourages it. However, I have not found such a thing in nodejs. If I want to run Sqlite3 on my machine so I can have easy to use database access, but postgres in production on Heroku, how would I do this in Nodejs? I can't see to find any tutorials on it.

Thank you!

*EDIT:* I meant to include Node.JS + Express.

Comment: FYI, comparing Ruby on Rails to node.js doesn't make much sense.  node.js is more analogous to Ruby; it's just a runtime, not a full web framework.  You may want to look into express or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible of course, but be aware that this is probably a bad idea: http://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity

If you don't want to go through the hassle of setting up postgres locally, you could instead use a free postgres plan on Heroku and connect to it from your local machine:

```
DATABASE_URL=url node server.j
```

A .env file can make this easier:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#copy-heroku-config-vars-to-your-local-env-file

Answer (score 1):

To switch between production and development Db you use different ports for running you application locally and on Heroku.
As Heroku by default runs the application to port 80 you have a some other port while running your app locally.

This will help you to figure out in run time if your application is running locally or in production and you can switch the Databases accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [`jugglingdb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jugglingdb) to do this:

> JugglingDB(3) is cross-db ORM for nodejs, providing common interface to access most popular database formats. Currently supported are: mysql, sqlite3, postgres, couchdb, mongodb, redis, neo4j and js-memory-storage (yep, self-written engine for test-usage only). You can add your favorite database adapter, checkout one of the existing adapters to learn how, it's super-easy, I guarantee.
>
> Jugglingdb also works on client-side (using WebService and Memory adapters), which allows to write rich client-side apps talking to server using JSON API.

I personally haven't used it, but having a common API to access all your database instances would make it super simple to use one locally and one in production - you could wire up some location detection without too much trouble as well and have it automatically select the target db depending on the environment it's in.